# multiple workflows in oozie coordinator

Tags: oozie-coordinator

I have three Workflow XML files such as WF1 WF2 WF3.  Can I link all these workflows in a single co-ordinator for the below actions?
WF1 is Time dependent
WF2 is File Dependency
WF3 is No Dependency of anything.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant link all three workflows in a single coordinator but you can create seperate coordinator for each workflow and link them using the bundle.

To learn more, http://developeriq.in/articles/2013/aug/28/scheduling-workflows-using-oozie-coordinator/